# How to join multiple tables and retrieve an aggregate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables and need to retrieve each EmployeeID, their Name, and their total WorkTime. My table structure is as follows:

**DEPT TABLE**

```
ID      DEPTNAME      DESIGNATION
1       MG            MANAGER
2       AN            ANALYTICS
3       DV            DEVELOPER
4       PM            PM
```

**WORK TABLE**

```
EMPID    WORKTIME   ID(FK TO TABLE DEPT)   DATE          
1        8          1                      09/15/2014
2        7          2                      09/15/2014
1        6          1                      09/16/2014
2        8          2                      09/16/2014
```

**EMP TABLE**

```
EMPID     NAME
1         SK
2         TK
3         MK
4         CK
```

I want all the Employee names with ID and the total working time, as below:

```
EMPID     NAME      WORKTIME     NOOFDATESWORKS
1         SK        14(8+6)      2
2         TK        15(7+8)      2
3         MK                     0  
4         CK                     0
```

*please note: employees can work for multiple departments

Comment: Are you sure you need a "stored procedure" or do you just need a query?

Comment: Looks like Homework !

Comment: So, you changed your question to add another column. It seems really like something you could easily add to the current answer, can't you modify the current code to add it?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  E.EmpID,
        E.Name,
        W.TotalWorkTime
FROM Emp E
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT EMID, SUM(WorkTime) TotalWorkTime
            FROM Work
            GROUP BY EMID) W
    ON E.EmpID =W.EMID
```

By the way, shouldn't the department Id be on the `Emp` table rather than the `Work` table?, as it is it doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Could be the employee works in multiple departments.

Comment: @MaxVernon Maybe, but still worthy of mention I think

Comment: Or maybe the work that was completed was for a certain department. I have seen this done in the past with IT for internal billing.

Comment: Acc the table is much more complex i need some idea. There is 6 table to join to get 12 field of record

Comment: @SauravKundu Sorry, don't know what you mean. This answers your question though

Comment: @Lamak i have changed the situation can you help

Comment: @SauravKundu I saw the change and I can help, but to be honest I rather not. The new requirement should be easily derived from the current code. I'm not trying to be condescending, but you should try to edit the code yourself otherwise you won't be able to learn from this